# Message body empty al usar msgHTML de phpmailer

Tags: php

Que tal amigos llevo ya un rato viendo el porque no envia el correo al destinatario, el fragmento lo tengo en la accion de un form, pero al no cumplir la condicion me salta al error "Message body empty", a ver si alguien puede ayudarme. Gracias

```
<?php
function sendmail($setFromEmail,$setFromName,$addReplyToEmail,$addReplyToName,$addAddressEmail,$addAddressName,$subject,$template){
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSendmail();

$mail->setFrom($setFromEmail, $setFromName);

$mail->addReplyTo($addReplyToEmail, $addReplyToName);

$mail->addAddress($addAddressEmail, $addAddressName);

$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents($template));


if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Error al enviar mensaje: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensaje enviado!";
}}sendmail('xx@dominio.com','quien envia','xx@dominio.com','a quien responde','xx@dominio.com','quien recibe','Prueba piloto','confirmation.html');?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, al no tener definido `$mail->IsHTML(true);` por defecto lo marca en `false` y si es asi, el mensaje de tu correo deberia ir en `$mail->Body();` asi que puedes agregar a tu configuracion

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

**EDICION**

tengo un codigo de PHPMailer asi :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "user";
$mail->Password = "pass";
$mail->setFrom('example@example.com', 'Contacto');
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email'], 'Contacto');
$mail->Subject = 'Contacto';
$message = file_get_contents('formato_mail.html');
$message = str_replace('%nombre%', $_POST['nombre'], $message);
$mail->msgHTML($message);
$mail->AltBody = 'Contacto';
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
if (!$mail->send()) {
    $result['status'] = 0;
    $result['mensaje'] = 'Ha ocurrido un error. Asegurate de que los datos que ingresaste sean correctos.';
} else {
    $result['status'] = 1;
    $result['mensaje'] = 'Gracias '.$_POST['nombre'].' por contactarte con nosotros. Resolveremos tus dudas a la brevedad.';
}
```

Comment: ya intente con $mail->IsHTML(true); mi buen y me sigue marcando el mismo error, si habia leido sobre eso, pero aun asi me marca el error

Comment: y si pones el contenido en el Body?

Comment: asi si funciona, pero lo que quiero es mostrar un plantilla html que tengo creada, para que no sea solo texto plano, por eso uso msgHTML

Comment: mira el ejemplo que te deje, yo tambien envio una plantilla que cree, donde tengo variables y las paso al contenido. Cuentame como te va!

Comment: vale, justo eso estoy analizando tu ejemplo, ahora te cuento como me fue, gracias mi buen ;)

Comment: no vas a creerlo mi buen pero me sale el mismo error usando tu ejemplo, no entiendo realmente porque

Comment: mi buen, acabo de encontrar el error, todo esta bien en cuanto al codigo que puse y tu codigo igual funciona perfecto, el problema era la plantilla que usaba, estaba dentro de un directorio que no debia, por eso marcaba el error fui probando en que folder debia estar hasta que me funciono, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, tu fragmento es mas sencillo y facil de usar sin crear función. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto, que bueno que mi codigo te haya servido!, saludos @IvanHernandez